# Consider the sequence where $a_1>0$, $ka_n>a_{n+1}$ and $0<k<1$. Can we say it converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I could get that

$a_1>k^n a_1 > a_{n+1}$ and therefore $0\geq\lim a_n$

But I can't find a lower bound for the squeeze theorem or something about monotonicity.

Any idea about this?

Comment: If you're not given that $a_n\geq0$, then this result is incorrect. The sequence could be $a_n=3-2n$, which diverges to $-\infty$.

Comment: The "result" is that the limit is $\leq 0$, I didn' say is convergent, that I'm asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not without additional conditions (e.g. if $\forall n\,(a_n\ge 0)\,$).

For example if $k=1/2$ and $a_1=1$ and $a_n=-n$ for $n>1.$